# Is setting container width:0 and child display:inline-block too hacky a way to get fitted divs in a vertical list?

Tags: css

Objective : To keep div fitted to content that is sized to the view-port, to do the minimum to style lists vertically or horizontally.

[image]

Is this CSS/HTML too hack? I want it to be the best and also the least (amount of writing):

```
.phosphor .vical {
        width:0; /* width 0 means we have a vertical list */
}
.phosphor .hical {
        width:auto; /* auto width means we get a responsive horizontal list */
}
.phosphor .vical a {
        display:inline-block;
}       
.phorphor .hical a {
        display:inline-block;
} 

<div class='phosphor'>
        <div class="vical">
                <a href="#V1">V1</a>
                <a href="#V2">V2</a>
                <a href="#V3">V3</a>
                <a href="#V4">V4</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#H1">H1</a>
        <a href="#H2">H1</a>
</div>
```

The rest of the code and a demo is here : http://jsfiddle.net/SaZUW/1/

Comment: A list of links?  Now if only there was a tag for expressing lists...

Comment: @cimmanon Resisting the urge to spell cinnamon. List is just part of it. I could always wrap it in a ul, ol, dl tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks ugly to me and I wouldn't recommend doing it that way.  If you're unable to modify the markup to use lists, you can use `display: table` instead.  It acts similar to inline-block for your purposes, but forces the elements to be on their own line and you can drop the `width: 0`:

http://jsfiddle.net/SaZUW/2/

```
.phosphor {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
}

.phosphor, .phosphor * {
    font: 5vw'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    color:transparent;
    background:black;
    text-shadow:0 0 1px lime;
}

.phosphor a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.phosphor a:focus, .phosphor a:active, .phosphor a:hover {
    outline:none;
    background:lime;
    text-shadow:0 0 1px black;
}

.phosphor .vical a {
    display:table;
}
```

Comment: That's cool actually. A few less lines. And uses display table. Nice.